# Loading data through template rendering?

Tags: django, python-3.x, templating

Currently I have some code in my index.html looking like:

```
<script>
    var episodes = [
        {% for episode in episodes_json %}
            {{episode|safe}},
        {% endfor %}
    ]
</script>
```

And in my view:

```
def view(request):
    return render("index.html", request, {"episodes": ...}
```

This loads some data that I display to my user. It works great, but I haven't seen this type of data loading in any django tutorials I've seen thus far. Are there are any downfalls to loading data this way, rather than through AJAX request or something?

This could apply to any templating language...

Comment: It is okay as long as the data is clean. Otherwise this approach is prone to XSS attack.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing definitely wrong with doing it this way, but it's a bit clunky. A much easier way is to just use JSON - there's no need to couple this with Ajax, it's perfectly suitable for sending directly. So in the view:

```
return render("index.html", request, {"episodes": json.dumps(...)})
```

and in the template just:

```
var episodes = JSON.parse({{ episodes|safe }});
```